# ansible-format-automatic-specification: Format string contains automatic field numbering specification

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

why I am seeing the 'F**ormat string contains automatic field numbering specification**' for the below line of code.

I see it executes succcessfully on the python 3.6 IDE, but when run with Ansible-Sanity its throwing error message

```
ansible-format-automatic-specification: Format string contains automatic field numbering specification
```

for below code.

```
def findhex(lid):
    lidHex = '{:04x}'.format(int(lid))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format string uses automatic field numbering, which is not available on all versions of Python that Ansible supports running modules on. You should explicitly number your fields if you want this test to pass.

```
lidHex = '{0:04x}'.format(int(lid))
```

Comment: Thanks flowerysong this helped  to resolve the  automatic field numbering

Comment: may you please have a look at the edited question as well

Comment: Same reason as before. `:04x` is a format specifier, not a field number.  Also, you should post new questions as new question, rather than replacing an old question.